# I'm publishing an RPG Maker MV app to the Google Playstore but the sample code from google is outdated

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk-expansion-files

I'm pretty new to programming so I've been using Rpg Maker MV. I made a game and now I'm trying to put it on the google playstore. I'm using android studio to export the game and since my app is well over 100 mb, I need to use an expansion file. I followed the tutorials I found online by various android studio users and one at developer.android.com. At one point, it said to use the downloader library scripts from google. Since I'm building my app in API 25, the DownloadNotification class won't work because the setLatestEventInfo method is no longer used. (See image) Could someone please help me with fixing it? It's used twice in the the class. 
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend instead of trying to expand game size, see what you can do to remove unused assets. There are a lot of files that get added when you first create a new project but you don't need them all. Have you seen this forum post: https://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?posts/754942/

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much! I'll try that now! Fingers crossed!